# Qiskit custom multi controlled gate

Tags: qiskit, transpile

I'm building a 3 qubit circuit with the *control-ry* rotation gate. The code is the following:

```
circ = QuantumCircuit(3)
circ.mcry(pi/8,
          q_controls=[0],
          q_target=2,
          use_basis_gates=False,
          mode='noancilla')
```

The result is that *cry* gate is NOT decomposed:

[image]

Is there a way to achieve the NOT decomposed circut on the ***multi**control-ry* gate? I mean instead of the following circuit:

[image]

for the following code:

```
circ = QuantumCircuit(3)
circ.mcry(pi/8,
          q_controls=[0, 1],
          q_target=2,
          use_basis_gates=False,
          mode='noancilla')
```

I want to recieve a single 2-control-ry gate.

I also tried to add these two lines:

```
gates = Aer.get_backend('qasm_simulator').configuration().basis_gates
transpile(circ, basis_gates=gates,optimization_level=0).draw(output='mpl')
```

thus the list of the utilized gates should be extended up to *['ccx', 'cp', 'cswap', 'csx', 'cu', 'cu1', 'cu2', 'cu3', 'cx', 'cy', 'cz', 'delay', 'diagonal', 'h', 'id', 'initialize', 'mcp', 'mcphase', 'mcr', 'mcrx', 'mcry', 'mcrz', 'mcswap', 'mcsx', 'mcu', 'mcu1', 'mcu2', 'mcu3', 'mcx', 'mcx_gray', 'mcy', 'mcz', 'multiplexer', 'p', 'pauli', 'r', 'rx', 'rxx', 'ry', 'ryy', 'rz', 'rzx', 'rzz', 's', 'sdg', 'swap', 'sx', 'sxdg', 't', 'tdg', 'u', 'u1', 'u2', 'u3', 'unitary', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'kraus', 'qerror_loc', 'quantum_channel', 'roerror', 'save_amplitudes', 'save_amplitudes_sq', 'save_density_matrix', 'save_expval', 'save_expval_var', 'save_probabilities', 'save_probabilities_dict', 'save_stabilizer', 'save_state', 'save_statevector', 'save_statevector_dict', 'set_density_matrix', 'set_stabilizer', 'set_statevector', 'snapshot']*, where *mcry* gate is also included. However it did not help.

Comment: do you mean you want to transpile the group of gate to 2 control ry gate?

Comment: I want to get a circuit not with 5 separate gates but with 1 CCRy gate

Comment: A similar question has been asked [here](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/16208/how-can-we-construct-a-control-control-y-rotation-ccry-gate-in-qiskit).

Comment: oh wow, didn't come across with it, thenks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking about this:

```
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit
from qiskit.circuit.library import RYGate
ccry = RYGate(np.pi/8).control(2,label=None)
circ = QuantumCircuit(3)
circ.append(ccry,[0,1,2])
circ.draw()
                
q_0: ─────■─────
          │     
q_1: ─────■─────
     ┌────┴────┐
q_2: ┤ Ry(π/8) ├
     └─────────┘
```

Second method, better way of making a control gate:

```
rry = RYGate(np.pi/8)
ccry = ControlledGate(name="cry", num_qubits=3, params=rry.params, num_ctrl_qubits=2, definition=rry.definition,ctrl_state='01', base_gate=rry) #ctrl_state to custom control state
circ = QuantumCircuit(3)
circ.append(ccry,[0,1,2])
circ.draw()
           
q_0: ─────■─────
          │     
q_1: ─────o─────
     ┌────┴────┐
q_2: ┤ Ry(π/8) ├
     └─────────┘
```

for more example, look at the test case from qiskit test file: https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra/blob/main/test/python/circuit/test_controlled_gate.py