# How to execute a qiskit circuit from strangeworks hub?

Tags: programming, qiskit, ibm-q-experience

I would like to execute a circuit in the strangeworks hub on IBM's "ibm_nairobi" system.

Could someone just please send me a general layout of execute and provide a command for stangeworks hub?

Comment: What is Strangeworks Hub? I searched "strangeworks hub" in quotes on Google and all I found was this question. It's very rare that I vote to close a question, but I feel like it's appropriate this time.

Comment: @user1271772 The OP probably prefer to this https://quantumcomputing.com/

Comment: Maybe, but I do not see "hub" anywhere on that website. The user has also been [warned  in the past](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/15475/a-problem-with-application-of-multi-controlled-rotation-gates#comment21435_15475) about not making their questions clear enough, and ignored the advice of Martin in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure to sync your IBMQ account. You can add in your IBMQ API token:

[image]

Once you do this, you can click on the hardware tab and see that your IBM Q account has linked to here.

[image]

Now you can create and run your circuit as the template given to your by StrangeWork:

[image]

```
import strangeworks.qiskit
import qiskit

qc = qiskit.QuantumCircuit(2, 2)
qc.h(0)
qc.cx(0, 1)
qc.measure([0, 1], [0, 1])

# uncomment the next line if you have more than one account
# backend = strangeworks.qiskit.get_backend("ibmqx2", account_id="ibm")
backend = strangeworks.qiskit.get_backend("ibmq_bogota")

job = qiskit.execute(qc, backend, shots=50)
result = job.result()
print("result:", result)
counts = result.get_counts()
print("counts:", counts)
```

If you check your IBMQ job status, then you will see the StrangeWork tag in your job:

[image]

Upon completion of your job, you can view your result just as you would through Qiskit.

[image]

Comment: it dosent work even after i add the ibms creidentials